# SSIS package powershell not working after deployment on the test server

Tags: powershell, ssis

I have a ssis package which has a execute process task, which calls a powershell file. The powershell simply check the csv file in one folder for any empty rows and than copy the file to new folder location.

It works fine with visual studio and when deployed on dev server, but when i deployed the code on test server it is not moving the files, but not throwing any error as well.

I executed the same powershell manually on the test server and it worked.

I have verified the following that everyone has read/write acess on the folders where files exists.

Is there any specific thing i need to do make it work on the test server?

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Did you set expression for Execute process task. **Argument :** Script that you want to execute, **Executable :** powershell path (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe), **WorkingDirectory:** Location for the file that you want to read and **StandardOutputVariable:** Variable that will hold script result

Comment: I have set the Argument and Executable but note the working directory and Output Variable. But without these it os working fine on Dev server. I have attached the snapshot of EPT

Comment: When I was working with PowerShell, on the server my user did not have permission in the D:\ drive. I had to use a Folder inside the drive like D:\Folder\.

Comment: I have already checked this. All users have read/Write permission on the folder

Comment: Set StandardErrorVariable and insert its value to a log table when your package gets executed in the dev environment. If any error occur in the script it will be logged. It might be possible script require some permission.